# How do I stop my boxes from stretching?

Tags: html, css, web

how do I stop this box from stretching? 
Here's the code and the result:

**CSS**:

```
.social {
    padding-left: 1000px;
    border: 5px inset black;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="social">
    <p>Social</p>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want padding-left:1000px?  its the padding that is stretching the container.

Comment: +1 above, margin may be what you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish @Lee360TheCoder? That will help us to know what suggestions to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have pointed out, your 1000px padding is adding the space. That's what the padding property does - it adds padding.

If you want 'social' to live in a 100px left column (my guess looking at your styles), remember that you will need to float your column, set it as an inline block, or lay it out with either CSS tables or flexbox.

Comment: Or you can use `margin-left` instead.

Comment: a margin adds space outside of the border. Padding adds space inside. Check out html box model